# Linux kernel: how to force TCP RST to be sent on incoming interface and not making routing decisions?

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

I'm working in an environment where services are isolated with no routing between them.
therefore I need to send `TCP RST` message through the incoming interface and not make any routing decisions at all since no route available to `dst` and the `RST` messages are lost.

I've added this line in Linux kernel tcp_v4_send_reset function:

```
arg.bound_dev_if = (skb->dev != dev_net(skb->dev)->loopback_dev) ? skb->dev->ifindex : 0;
```

but I can see from tcpdumps that the RST message was not sent on the incoming interface but routing decision was made.

any help?

did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to modify kernel to achieve this, Use `ip rule` instead.

first mark connection coming from different interface, and save the mark in conntrack table (I'm using eth2/4 as example):

```
iptables -t mangle -A routemark -i eth2 -j MARK --set-mark 0x100
iptables -t mangle -A routemark -i eth4 -j MARK --set-mark 0x200
iptables -t mangle -A routemark -m mark ! --mark 0x0/0xff00 -j CONNMARK --save-mark --mask 0xff00
```

Then create rt_table for each interface in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`, insert default route into the table:

```
ip route add default via gateway-ip-eth2 dev eth2 table rt-eth2
ip route add default via gateway-ip-eth4 dev eth4 table rt-eth4
```

For every outgoing packet, restore connection mark to packet mark, and lookup corresponding rt_table:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m connmark ! --mark 0x0/0xff00 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark --mask 0xff00
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x100/0xff00 ! iif eth2 lookup rt-eth2
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x200/0xff00 ! iif eth4 lookup rt-eth4
```

So all responding packet will be sent to the interface where the origin packet comes from.